MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.Execute not working when deploying to web app in Azure but works fine locally when pointing to db in azure
I have a problem with my automatic database migrations with my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. It works fine when running my app locally, while pointing to the SQL database in Azure, but when I deploy it to the App Service in Azure, it fails. I'm using the admin credentials in my connection string at this point, so it really confuses me.
I followed this Youtube tutorial for context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9eEEFGgSHw
I'm using this code in my Program.cs:

I get this error in the log in Azure when the app deploys and tries to (what I guess) is running the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.Execute:

I have no idea why this happens (I see that it says operation.ErrorCode:InsufficientAccountPermissions), and the ONLY difference is that the app is deployed in Azure, so it really confuses me how it can update the cloud database just fine when running locally, but not when deployed.
I tried using a user with db_reader, db_writer and db_owner permissions, but switched to the admin credentials directly in the connection string, but the error still persists.
I tried allowing "Access from other Azure resources" to no avail. Disabling the automatic migrations code lets the app deploy and run (but the whole purpose is automatic migrations).
I have absolutely no idea how it can break just because I'm deploying and not running it locally, as the local build can update the cloud database without issue.

I found this repo(https://github.com/kartik786-git/WebApiefcoremigrationautomatic) from the video you shared, is it same as yours ?

Please share the format of your connectionstring, so that I can test in my side.

It's almost the same, except i dont have the extension folder with the startupdbextension, i also use out-of-process. My connection string format is: Server=tcp:{your_sqlserver}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_database};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_login};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Please check webapp down logs inside Diagnose and solve problems in azure portal.

This is what the webapp down logs say: errors link also now im using the exact repo that you linked

Hi jgd, please share the repo and tell us the detailed steps, then we can investigate it. You should hide your sensitive information like db connectionstring.

I am using this repo: https://github.com/jonasdamsbo/mytestrepo
, in Azure DevOps, i make a pipeline that starts when pushing to master, which triggers a release that points to and deploys to an App Service in Azure Portal. When the release is done deploying, i get the error in the logs that i posted in my original question. If you want to try and recreate it, just make a new project like in my repository, make a Azure DevOps pipeline and release, make an App Service in Azure Portal and deploy your release to the App Service via Azure DevOps.


MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.Execute:

The above error occurs mostly due to the version mismatch. Check the version both in local and azure portal. Try by providing contributor role instead of reader, writer, owner. Try with the below code it successfully worked both in local and in azure portal. Use the connection string pattern used in the below code.
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlblogdb": "Server=<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<db_name>;User ID=pbadmin1;Password=<password>;Connection Timeout=30"
  }
}

Below is the controller.cs:
namespace _78515051.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BlogController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IBlogService _blogService;

        public BlogController(IBlogService blogService)
        {
            _blogService = blogService;
        }

        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var blogs = await _blogService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(blogs);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
        {
            var blog = await _blogService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if(blog == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(blog);
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Blog blog)
        {
            var createdBlog = await _blogService.CreateAsync(blog);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = createdBlog.Id}, createdBlog);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id,  Blog updatedBlog)
        {
            var blog = await _blogService.UpdateAsync(id, updatedBlog);
            if (blog == null)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }
            return NotFound();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var blog = await _blogService.DeleteAsync(id);  
            if(blog == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return NoContent(); 
        }
    }
}

Below is the entity used to create a db and a table:
namespace _78515051.Entity
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string Description { get; set; } 
        public string Author { get; set; }  
    }
}

Output:


This still didn't work for me. Did you publish it to an App Service in azure portal through Azure DevOps?

Yes, I published it to Azure portal through Azure DevOps.

Can you put it in a bit more detail what you did? Sorry but i don't think we're quite doing the same think, as mine won't work from a freshly created project, fresh App Service, and fresh DevOps release
